# bluetooth error: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject:

Tags: usb, bluetooth, hardware, dmesg

Using ubuntu 16.04 after accidentally removing my bluetooth headset device from the bluetooth manager device list it is either no longer visible in a bluetooth search, or it shows up for a few seconds in the device list during a search and then disappears. I'm now unable to use my bluetooth headset.

If I run blueman-applet from a terminal I see an exception during the search followed by the device getting deleted.

```
>__init__ (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py:26)
caching initial properties 
ERROR:dbus.connection:Exception in handler for D-Bus signal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 230, in maybe_handle_message
    self._handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
    handler(name, value, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/GameControllerWakelock.py", line 36, in on_device_property_changed
    klass = Device(path).get_properties()["Class"] & 0x1fff
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.Properties = self.Device.get_properties()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
    raise parse_dbus_error(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
    return self.__properties_interface.GetAll(self.get_interface_name())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
```

Help appreciated - kindof important to my work.

relevant error:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
```

Comment: Almost sounds like the batteries in the headset are getting weak and it is quitting pairing mode early

Comment: Actually if I run the blueman-applet from a terminal I can see that there is an exception being logged. can't seem to post it here so I'll add to the original question.

Comment: Uninstall Blueman and see if the same problems happen with Ubuntu's bluetooth manager as having 2 bluetooth managers can cause issues